# Criação de Tabela de Jogos

Tags: javascript, refatoração

Escrevi esse código para organizar as equipes que deverão se enfrentar na Copa:

```
<script>
var dados = {
    "grupo1" : [
        {"selecao" : [{"nome":"brasil"},{"resultado" : [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]},
        {"selecao" : [{"nome":"croacia"},{"resultado" : [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]},
        {"selecao" : [{"nome":"camaroes"},{"resultado" : [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]},
        {"selecao" : [{"nome":"mexico"},{"resultado" : [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]}
    ],
};

var jsonData = eval(dados);

alert(jsonData.grupo1[0].selecao[0].nome);

document.write(jsonData.grupo1[0].selecao[0].nome+" x "+jsonData.grupo1[1].selecao[0].nome+"<br />");
document.write(jsonData.grupo1[3].selecao[0].nome+" x "+jsonData.grupo1[2].selecao[0].nome+"<br />");
document.write(jsonData.grupo1[0].selecao[0].nome+" x "+jsonData.grupo1[3].selecao[0].nome+"<br />");
document.write(jsonData.grupo1[2].selecao[0].nome+" x "+jsonData.grupo1[1].selecao[0].nome+"<br />");
document.write(jsonData.grupo1[1].selecao[0].nome+" x "+jsonData.grupo1[3].selecao[0].nome+"<br />");
document.write(jsonData.grupo1[2].selecao[0].nome+" x "+jsonData.grupo1[0].selecao[0].nome+"<br />");
```

Entretanto, como são vários grupos, se continuar a organizá-los dessa forma irá resultar em um código muito grande, gostaria de saber se há um forma melhor de fazê-lo?

Comment: Vamos dar o prêmio de "javascript incomum que vai demorar um pouco para que possamos entender"? Brincadeira. @Hunteros você está usando alguma biblioteca ou prefere que respondemos sem usar-las?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode organizar os dados de outra forma, isso vai depender deles e como você irá apresentá-los. Um exemplo é colocá-los em uma `Array`, para facilitar o acesso aos diferentes grupos.

```
var dados = [
    [
        {"selecao": [{"nome":"brasil"},  {"resultado": [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]},
        {"selecao": [{"nome":"croacia"}, {"resultado": [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]},
        {"selecao": [{"nome":"camaroes"},{"resultado": [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]},
        {"selecao": [{"nome":"mexico"},  {"resultado": [{"a":0},{"a":4},{"a":2}]}]}
    ] /* , [grupo 2, etc] */
];
```

O `eval` não era necessário e o `alert` suponho que seria para testar.

Agora, vamos criar uma variável para organizar os jogos: nesse caso usei uma Array que contém os jogos, que podem ser organizados em `[selecao-1, selecao-2]` ou objetos:

```
var jogos = [[0, 1], [3, 2], [0, 3], /* ... */];
```

Então vamos mostrar os dados:

```
document.write(jogos.map(function (times) {
  return dados[0][times[0]].selecao[0].nome + " x " + dados[0][times[1]].selecao[0].nome;
}).join('<br>'));
```

Caso se você for usar uma biblioteca ou caso os dados precisem de mostrados de outra forma pode-se alterar esse último bloco de código para adaptar-se a isso.

Ainda, dependendo da maneira que você organizou o HTML é possível deixar de usar o `document.write` e usar funções como `.appendChild` e `.insertBefore`, evitando que o HTML seja reprocessado, o que torna-o mais rápido.